# Number theory challenge from the Russian Mathematical Olympiad in 2000

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Determine whether there exist pairwise relatively prime integers $a,b$ and $c$ with  $a,b,c>1$ such that: $$b|2^a+1, \quad c|2^b+1, \quad  a|2^c+1.$$

---

The official solution makes the assumption $a<b,c$. Why is that? I understand that divisibility relation is cyclic, but what is the rationale behind making such an assumption? Why can't we assume that $1<a<b<c$ ?

Comment: Perhaps assuming $b<c$ is simply unnecessary.

Comment: That's because once you have that the minimum is chosen, you can't say which is the minimum between $b$ and $c$. Indeed, $b$ is the number which divides $2^a+1$, while $c$ is the number such that $a$ divides $2^c+1$: $b,c$ have not symmetric roles once you choose that the minimum is $a$.

Comment: Clearly, one of these numbers is less than the one next to it. Let's call that number $a$.